# Android App takes a long time to load

Tags: java, android

I am using the code below to connect to wifi. When the app loads, it just shows the black screen and then the button will appear to disconnect from wifi. Is there a way so that the button will be visible right away? Also is there a way I can show the progress of the application loading so a user wont think it is hung up?

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. 
 * @return */



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button OffWifi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.offwifi);
    OffWifi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
      public void onClick(View v) {                 
          WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);          
          }        
      });



    TextView tv = new TextView(this);       
    TextView status = new TextView(this);                  


    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();  
    wc.SSID = "\"Test\""; //IMP! This should be in Quotes!! 

    wc.hiddenSSID = true; 
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;      
    wc.priority = 10; 
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK); 
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);  
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA); 
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN); 
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED); 
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP); 
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP); 
    wc.preSharedKey = "\"Password\""; 
    WifiManager  wifiManag = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE); 
    boolean res1 = wifiManag.setWifiEnabled(true); 
    int res = wifi.addNetwork(checkPreviousConfiguration(wc)); 
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res ); 
    boolean es = wifi.saveConfiguration(); 
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "saveConfiguration returned " + es ); 
    boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);    
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );   

    tv.setText("You are now connected!  " +
            "Version 1.1");

    status.setText("The was an error connecting, please try again.");

       //@Override

    try {

        Thread.sleep(5000);

         ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 

         if (connec != null && (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)){  
                //You are connected, do something online. 
                setContentView(tv);

            }else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ) {              
                //Not connected.         
               setContentView(status);
            }  

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





}

public WifiConfiguration checkPreviousConfiguration(WifiConfiguration wc) {
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
 List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();     
    for(WifiConfiguration config : configs) {         
        if(config.SSID.equals(wc.SSID)) return config;     
        }     
    return wc; 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine the `Thread.sleep(5000)` is the cause of the delay.

Basically you're telling the app to stop for 5 seconds.

Comment: +1 and please note that nobody should use `Thread.sleep(n)` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, its the Thread.sleep(5000) thats causing the delay. Because OnCreate is called from the UI thread, the whole thing pauses. If you create a runnable, then use that in an instance of a new thread, you can call sleep() for however long you want without choking the UI thread. That is the main cause of many 'XXX is not responding' bugs. Or, if you dont want to get into threading, have a look at the ASyncTask that Android offers.

EDIT:

If you just want to display a message, a Toast is the best thing to do. Accessing the UI from another thread is a little cumbersome, but not impossible. One way would be to Package the whole try block into a runnable, like so:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
            try {

                Thread.sleep(5000);

                ConnectivityManager connec =(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 

                if (connec != null && (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)){  
                    //You are connected, do something online. 
                    //Have to edit the UI on the UI thread
                    Runnable tempRun = new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            setContentView(tv);
                        }
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(r);
                }else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ) {              
                    //Not connected. 
                    //NEEDS TO BE SAME AS ABOVE.        
                    setContentView(status);
                }  

           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
     }
}
```

then you can call `Thread t = new Thread(r);` and `t.start();`. Ive not tested that, but im pretty sure thats accurate. The setContentView calls will change the entire layout, and thats probably not what you want, but is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Ok thank you, the reason I was doing that is I didnt want to display the message the wifi was connected while it was still working. With that been said is there a way I can have the wait still work? Or somehow only display the message if connected?